# (Lagrange multiplier) Different answers for two different methods

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I would like to find the coordinates which maximize the function $T(x,y,z)=2x+4xy+3z^2$ under the restriction $x^2+4y^2+4z^2-12=0$.

First, using the method of Lagrange multiplier leads to the answer $(x,y,z)=\left( \sqrt{\frac{47+\sqrt{97}}{8}}, \frac{-1+\sqrt{97}}{8}, 0 \right)$.

But, another direct method that eliminates the z by using restriction condition and equates partial derivatives of T with respect to x and y equals 0 leads to the answer $(x,y,z)=\left( \frac{-12}{7}, \frac{-8}{7}, \pm \frac{\sqrt{47}}{7} \right)$.

The right answer is first method(This problem is in Korean math exam and the answer is opened to the public.

I don't know why the second direct method leads to wrong answer...

Comment: Those GIFs are almost unreadable. Please use MathJax for equations on this site. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: When you plug in $z^2=3-y^2-x^2/4$ back into the expression of $T$ you have to check that $3-y^2-x^2/4\geq 0$, otherwise $z^2$ doesn't make sense. Also, notice that you can't just solve for $\partial T/\partial x=\partial T/\partial y=0$ in this case, since you also have to consider the border $3-y^2-x^2/4=0$. In fact, the given correct solution lies on the border, and that's why you haven't found it.

Comment: $\left(-\frac{12}{7}, -\frac{8}{7},\pm\frac{\sqrt{47}}{7}\right)$ are *saddle* points because Hessian matrix has negative determinant $$H(x,y)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{3}{2} & 4 \\
 4 & -6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ $\det H=-7$

Comment: Dear Federico Clerici
Thank you so much for editing my poor equation and your answer!
But it is not yet clear, because second answer satisfies inequality $$3-y^2-\frac{x^2}{4} = z^2 >0$$.
Raffaele(below your answer) said that the second answers are saddle point.
But I think that Lagrange method can find the saddle point also(because saddle point is the stationary point.).
I think I have to consider more detailedly....

Comment: Dear Raffaele
Thank you for your answer!
I have not known what is Hessian matrix.
Thanks to you, I find the information of Hessian matrix.